# Help Required on track active directory changes

Tags: active-directory

I am going to write a small software to track active directory changes. I need an expert opinion from you. I want to display information about What ( with before and after values), When, Where and Who of any change in AD. 
I am going to implement this by one of the following way
1. Change Notification Control
2. DirSync Control

Both of these method give us the attribute that are changed and we can compare new values with some dump in SQL Server to get old values.

My problem is how can I find “Who” has made this change. I have tried but there is no attribute “LastModifiedBy” in active directory. Please give your opinion how can I track who has made this change.

--Faisal Iqbal

Answer (score 0):

My company uses ActiveRoles from Quest.  No one actually makes changes directly to AD; all changes are done through ActiveRoles so we have that type of auditing (and a lot more benefits.)

Comment: actually I have to implement this in .NET using SDS or SDS.Protocols. My question is is there any attribute in active directory object where I can find who has made the changes to a specific object.

--Faisal

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use AD Auditing?

Comment: we are going to develop an in-house application for Auditing with some extended functionality.